# After updating XAMPP, existing Wordpress sites redirect to an install page?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, xampp, localhost

I recently updated to the current version of XAMPP. Before the update, I made a backup of all my htdoc files (all Wordpress installs), and then uninstalled XAMPP.

But I failed to export my databases. (My bad.)

Now when I try to access my local sites, I am brought to the 5-minute installation page for Wordpress—with the notification that users already exist. [(Screenshot of the Wordpress install page here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2kwk.png) The install process only produces database errors and tells me that tables already or don't exist. At the bottom of the page I am told to log-in...which brings me to a 404 error.

Ugh.

I have tried exporting the .sql files I'm particularly desirous to save and importing them in new databases...but to no avail.

Any insight? Are my sites toast, or what can I do to restore all my work?

Comment: Check with phpMyAdmin to verify your data (pretty sure there is a XAMPP uninstall option to keep or destroy data).

Comment: Poked around a bit in phpMyAdmin and discovered that I get a #1932 error when I select files in my databases; the error message says "Table ___ doesn't exist in server." What can I do? @DaveCoast

Answer (score 0):

Learned through another coder that all my data is indeed toast. Don't know exactly how this happened, but as a warning to y'all: **Find and follow instructions to upgrade XAMPP *before* proceeding and take every precaution you can!**